# Test error spikes at dimension half of sample size in linear model without regularization

Tags: linear-model, error, eigenvalues

I am training a basic linear model, with input data $x(n)$ and target data $t(n)$. Now, I want to make a model of dimension $d$, such that

$$ y(\textbf{x}) = w_0 + \sum_{i=1}^d w_ix_i = w_0 + \textbf{w}^\top \textbf{x}. $$

Weight terms are computed using sum-of-squares, so that

$$ \textbf{w} = (\textbf{X}^\top \textbf{X})^{-1} \textbf{X}^\top \textbf{t} = \text{pinv}\{\textbf{X}\} \textbf{ t} $$

The pseudo-inserve is required since $\textbf{X}$ is not square. Now, this works well on our data set, implemented in Matlab, but when the amount of dimensions is exactly half of the training size $$ d \approx N/2, $$ we observe a clear peak in test error. This is seen on the attached image.

[image: Model performance]

*Observation: $d=9$ provides the best performance, but there is a clear peak in test error when dimension is exactly half the sample size.*

I have been told that there is a mathematical explanation to this, and it should lie within that the eigenvalues of $\textbf{X}$ take a dive towards zero, such that when the pseudo-inverse is taken, it grows large. However, I can not seem to visualize this. $\textbf{X}$ is $d \times N$ dimensional, so I could take the eigenvalues on $\textbf{X}^\top \textbf{X}$, but they do not behave as expected.

Anyone who can explain it to me?

Code:

```
% X is input data
% last_train is length of total data - d 

%Training set
Xtrain = X(1:last_train,:); Xtest = X((last_train+1):N,:);
Ttrain = T(1:last_train); Ttest = T((last_train +1):N);

w = pinv(Xtrain) * Ttrain;
Ytrain = Xtrain*w;
Ytest = Xtest*w;
Y = X*w;
errtrain = mean((Ytrain-Ttrain).^2)/var;
errtest  = mean((Ytest-Ttest).^2)/var;
```